# how do i match the users input with keywords in my text file and and give an output

Tags: python, input, match

i need to ask the user for an input (what problem do you have?)
i created a file that has the possible problems as well as possible solutions to these problems.the program should print out the solution if the user input mathces the keyword in the file. here is the code:

```
print ("welcome to our automated trouble shooting system")

def do_again():
    datadict = {}
    with open('prosol.txt') as file: 
        for rec in file:
            rec = rec.split(':')
            problem = rec[0]
            answer = rec[1] 
            problem = problem.split(" ")
            for item in problem: 
                datadict[item] = answer



    user_problem = input('What is the problem?: ') 
    print(datadict[user_problem]) 


    repeat = input("do you have any other problems.\n1. Yes\n2. No\n") 
    try_again = ["1","2"] 
    while repeat not in try_again: 
        repeat = input("do you have any other problems.(please answer using the corrinsponding numbers)\n1. Yes\n2. No\n") 
    if repeat == "1": 
        (do_again()) 
    elif repeat == "2": 
        print("bye. i hope it helped you") 
        quit() 

(do_again())
```

it works when i use one word keywords. for example

```
welcome to our automated trouble shooting system
What is the problem?: **screen**
 if your screen is broken, then you will have to replace it. if it is frozen the try turning off your phone and the turn it on again.

do you have any other problems.
1. Yes
2. No
```

but it doesnt work if i put a full sentence.for example

```
welcome to our automated trouble shooting system
What is the problem?: **my screen doesnt work**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\Downloads\task2\mine\task 2.py", line 38, in <module>
(do_again()) ##calling the function


File "C:\Users\hp\Downloads\task2\mine\task 2.py", line 18, in do_again
    print(datadict[user_problem]) ##print the value of the kye selected

KeyError: 'my screen doesnt work'
```

i feel like this is happening because i am using a dictonary. although i know this is the rerason , idont know how to fix it. can someone help me pls.
here is the file just in case you need it:

```
screen Screen SCREEN display Display DISPLAY : if your screen is broken, then you will have to replace it. if it is frozen the try turning off your phone and the turn it on again.

battery Battery BATTERY power Power POWER : if your phone is out of charge and you cant seem to charge it then you will have to replace either your battery or charger.

audio Audio AUDIO sound Sound SOUND : to fix you sound you can go to settings, then display. there you can change the setting of your devices sound
```

also i am a newbie at python. so you will have to bear with me with your explanations

Comment: quick tip: instead of checking for lots of different case variations of a single word, use[`str.lower`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) to just compare the all-lowercase-input. e.g.: `if input("> ").lower() == 'screen'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling a key directly from the user input. You need to search for the keyword before you try to call the key or you can put in a try except clause to catch exceptions where the key they're calling isn't in the dictionary.

```
user_answer = input("What's your problem?")
split_answer = user_answer.split(" ")
for option in datadict.keys():
    if option in split_answer:
        print(datadict[option])
```

Comment: and how do i search for a key?

Comment: So let's say the user inputs "My computer screen is broken" if you do user_input_query.split(" ") and search in the split list for your key words you can call the answers based on their answer. I'll put an edit in my post, 2 seconds

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your dictionary has an entry for `'screen'` (or `'**screen**'`, I'm not sure judging by your code), but not for any complete sentence.

You need to identify the keywords that indicate problems in the user input first, then print the solutions stored by your dictionary.

Here is a simple demo that should get the point across.

```
>>> answers = {'screen': 'do A', 'water': 'do B', 'power': 'do C'}
>>> user_input = input('what is the problem? ')
what is the problem? my screen is damaged from a water spill
>>> words = user_input.lower().split()
>>> for problem in words:
...     if problem in answers:
...         print(answers[problem])
... 
do A
do B
```

(I am assuming that you are using Python 3, if you are using Python 2 use `raw_input` instead of `input`.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your record file looks like:

`question1:answer1
question2:answer2
...
question_n:answer_n`

the error might lie in here:

```
def do_again():
    datadict = {}
    with open('prosol.txt') as file: 
        for rec in file:
            rec = rec.split(':')
            problem = rec[0]
            answer = rec[1] 
            problem = problem.split(" ")
            for item in problem: 
                datadict[item] = answer
```

The `problem = problem.split(" ")` just split a whole sentence into words, and the `datadict` only stores those words as keys.

for example:

`how old are you:16`

In your code, the datadict is like :

`{
    'how': 16,
    'old': 16,
    'are': 16,
    'you': 16
}`

which is not what you want